# PWA .desktop file opening new browser window instead of the app

Tags: gnome, chromium, webapps, brave

I've created a web app with Brave's *Create shortcut* tool and it appeared on my desktop as *.desktop* file. I've "allowed launching" but it keeps opening a new empty Brave window instead of the correct web app address.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=YouTube
Exec=/snap/brave/123/opt/brave.com/brave/brave-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=agimnkijcaahngcdmfeangaknmldooml
Icon=brave-agimnkijcaahngcdmfeangaknmldooml-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_agimnkijcaahngcdmfeangaknmldooml
```

Ubuntu 21.04

GNOME Shell 3.38.4

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad you have to download Brave via apt-get, not snap

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 this is a problem for Brave even when it is installed via the *.deb. And now Chromium is only a snap -- even when you install it via deb it still installs the snap. So using Chromium to install the PWA isn't a solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple solution If you want to keep the snap version.**

I had found it that downloading via apt will fix the issue but then I found that brave is banned in my country (maybe because it comes with Tor), Which made it impossible to access braves website/repo without a vpn, but it meant that I will need to keep checking for updates manually and turn on and off my vpn if there is any update available, So I had to stick with the snap version.

But then I figured out a workaround.

**Solution:**

- In the `.desktop` file that brave created change the `/snap/brave/132/opt/brave.com/brave/brave-browser` to brave's default executable (`snap/bin/brave` in my case) part from the `Exec`'s value.
- (Optional) Set the `Icon`'s value of your choice (provide Icon's path), default's to Brave's Icon.
- Move the `.desktop` file to `/home/username/.local/share/applications`.

**Done!**
The PWA will appear as an App in the menu.